# Edges missing while generating PNG from SVG in Internet Explorer using Dagre D3

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, dagre-d3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcS5P.png)

I was working on creating a snapshot (PNG using canvas drawing) of the graphs created using a library. The rendering (both svg and canvas) work perfectly fine with chrome, but doesn't show the edges and styling on the node in Internet Explorer.

Any idea if I have to do something more to get this working in IE? Screenshot for reference.

The first part in the image shows the actual SVG and the part below shows the generated canvas drawing.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? What library? Can you post a demo of the problem? WIthout code it is really hard to be able to help

Comment: I got through this issue :). Earlier, I was trying to PNG from SVG using the toDataURL in canvas, which erred out with security issue. Later, tried canvg which brought me to Stackoverflow to post this question as the edges were not  showing up in PNG. The solution which was to set the CSS file using <defs>[CDATA ...as the first node as below:
d3.select("svg").insert("defs", ":first-child").append("style").attr("type", "text/css").text(styles);
Than:
d3.select("svg").append("defs").append("style").attr("type","text/css").html( styles );

So after this change, canvg lib worked like charm